# Using JWT to GET User Info

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, jwt, express-jwt

I'm currently experimenting with JWT and the MERN stack. I have JWT set up to authenticate users. I set the JWT in local storage. How do I make a GET query request to my MongoDB using purely the JWT? I want to just pull info for that specific user using purely the JWT token. Do I have to store User.id as well in local storage and use that to make a query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While creating the token, add user id in the payload. In all subsequent API calls, get user id from payload and use it in the query.